# View [auth.login] not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working on login part of application where i am creating two seperate login for admin and user.
My Controller structure is like :

```
 Controller -    Admin (For Admin)
       LoginController.php
       -- Auth
          login.blade.php
       ....   Auth  (For Normal user)
       LoginController.php
       ...

Views:

 Admin 
   login.blade.php
 auth 
   login.blade.php
```

till now i'm working on the admin part.

```
LoginController.php

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect admins after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.auth.login');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'   => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password
        ], $request->get('remember'))) {
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
        }
        return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    /*public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        return redirect()->route('admin.login');
    } */
}
```

> RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        switch($guard){
            case 'admin':
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect('/admin');
                }
                break;
            default:
                if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect('/');
                }
                break;
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

> Authenticate.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

> web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix'  =>  'admin'], function () {

    Route::get('login', 'Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('login', 'Admin\LoginController@login')->name('admin.login.post');
    Route::get('logout', 'Admin\LoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');

    //Route::get('dashboard', 'Admin\LoginController@dashboard')->name('admin.dashboard');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function () {

        Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
            return view('admin.dashboard.index');
        })->name('admin.dashboard');

    });
```

whenever i access dashboard throgh url i get View[auth.login] not found.

Comment: First you can try with `php artisan cache:clear`, but I can see a couple of things I don't understand. One is your route `Route::post('login', 'Admin\LoginController@login')` it is pointing to the login function, but in your controller the function to attempt login is called dashboard. Could you explain that? Another, I see that both in the controller and in the middleware you redirect to '/admin', but I don't see in your routes any with that uri, only with '/admin/dashboard'. It may not be related, but it would be something to review. Do you have that route?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ: I have updated my code in the question above. Only the issue is when i hit http://localhost/admin/dashboard i am redirected to http://localhost/login where i get error View[auth.login] not found but the redirection if i hit this dashboard url should be http://localhost/admin/login.

Comment: I can see your dashboard route is protected by `['middleware' => ['auth:admin']]`. Can you show us that middleware? In Laravel 5.8, should be [/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.8/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php)

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ: Added code of authenticate.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the file [Authenticate.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.8/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php)  to receive the guard name in redirectTo method.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guards = [];

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @param  string[] ...$guards
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $this->guards = $guards;

        return parent::handle($request, $next, ...$guards);
    }

    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
            if (reset($this->guards) === 'admin') {
                return route('admin.login');
            }
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it may be necessary to execute `php artisan cache:clear` after the change.

[source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26292#issuecomment-433949245)

Comment: i'm getting this error: Call to undefined function App\Http\Middleware\array_first()

Comment: or you can use reset `if (reset($this->guards) === 'admin')`

Comment: Thanks it is working for admin but i want to know in future if i add one more guard for user and add checkout route such as when user enters http://localhost/checkout then the redirection should be to http://localhost/login then will this middleware will work.

Comment: It should work. It will only redirect to 'admin.login' if in the middleware auth you pass as first parameter admin `['middleware' => ['auth:admin']]`, but if you do not pass any parameters  `['middleware' => ['auth']]`, this condition `if (reset($this->guards) === 'admin')` will be false and the function will return `return route('login');`